# via share on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, share

I'm trying to share content in Android, using intent ACTION_SEND like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Сонгох"));
}
```

Message is not shown when sharing on Facebook using intent for Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below code will help you.

The Facebook app sharing work is to share **only a link with no text:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.com/");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me